# Asp.Net MVC : Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm recieving the following error message,

> A public action method 'RenderMenu'
>   was not found on controller
>   'Web.Controllers.SiteController'.

However this action DOES exist and the controller does exist (As it work everywhere on the site) I looked at the inner exception.

> Execution of the child request failed.
>   Please examine the InnerException for
>   more information.

(This is the inner exception...)

Stack Trace

> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func)    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean
>   preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath
>   filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride)

Now, we have a website set-up with a dynamic menu system so we are using RenderAction() on a generic controller to build this menu system up.

```
<% Html.RenderAction("RenderMenu", "Site"); %>
```

This call is made from the MasterPage and it works fine until there was a validation error like so,

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserModel UserToAdd)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(UserToAdd);
            }
            //Run some validation
            if (_UserService.DoesEmailExist(UserToAdd.EMail))
            {
                TempData["error"] = "Email Address Already in use!";
                return View(UserToAdd);
            }

            //Add the user

            TempData["info"] = "User Added - " + UserO.ID;
            return View("Success");
        }
```

It works fine when there this is a new user, but if someone enters an email that already exist we get the above error. THis RenderAction Method works all over the site (This is the first form we have added)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm... you should not use RenderAction. i know this is nice, but with that, your view excutes an action. therefore you do not have the correct flow.
what would be the right solution is, having in the "base" controller a code, that adds the MenuModel as Lazy into the ViewData. and on RenderPartial("MenuView", ViewData["MenuModel"])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed:

The RenderAction() Method is below

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RenderMenu()
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
```

Removing the HttpGet Attribute has resolved the issue.

```
        public ActionResult RenderMenu()
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
```

Would love to know why?

Comment: because if you have the Get Attribute, it would only allow get requests. but if there is a post request it cannot find the method.

what i think is, if its success, you redirect to another action (with get) but when its failed, it should display the post request, therefore searching for a menu method accepting post.

Comment: Had similar issue. Adding [HttpPost] didn't help at all, but removing [HttpGet] did. Why?

Answer (score -1):

This is because your parent request is an `[HttpPost]`, and the child request operates in the same verb as the parent.  If your method is marked as `[HttpGet]`, it will not respond to `[HttpPost]` requests.  Hitting the action directly through your browser works because that is a `GET`. Hitting the action as a child action in the context of a `POST` will not work.