# Html.RenderAction Throws System.Web.HttpException, due to Child Request Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a Registration Page in ASP.NET MVC but there is an issue with one Field in particular. The "Country" field, my intention is to read the countries from a locally stored JSON file and render a partial view (which consists of just a Drop Down Box). However, when I run the code and try and navigate to the Registration page I get the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.

Looking closer at the Exception I see the following:

> $exception    {"Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information."}  System.Web.HttpException
>
> InnerException  {"The controller for path '/Account/Register' was not found or does not implement IController."}    System.Exception {System.Web.HttpException}

Here is the code:

**Partial View**

```
using MyWatch.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyWatch.Controllers
{
    public class CountrySearchController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CountrySearch()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Alex Combe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MyWatch\\MyWatch\\App_Data\\CountryList.json"))
                {
                    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Countries countries = new Countries();
                    countries.countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Country>>(json);
                    return PartialView(countries);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return View(new Countries());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*@{Html.RenderAction("CountrySearch", "Search");}*@
        @{Html.RenderAction("CountrySearch", "Search");}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial View Controller**

```
namespace MyWatch.Controllers
{
    public class CountrySearchController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CountrySearch()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Alex Combe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MyWatch\\MyWatch\\App_Data\\CountryList.json"))
                {
                    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Countries countries = new Countries();
                    countries.countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Country>>(json);
                    return PartialView(countries);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return View(new Countries());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Partial View's Model**

```
namespace MyWatch.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Countries
    {
        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public IList<Country> countries;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you would remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute temporarily, and execute the Child Action directly in the Browser, will it work?

Comment: Are some parts of the Application Forms Authentication enabled? The appearance of path `Account/Register` leads me to the assumption that, driven by some circumstance/mistake (e.g. Child Action is Authentication enabled while parent form isn't) it tries to redirect you to the Account Area. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Thank you both for getting back to me so quickly. I had to change the partial View's code but yes I can call it directly and I just get the dropdown box rendered on an empty webpage. However, the Dropdown list is only populated with _System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem_

Comment: `@model MyWatch.Models.Countries
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "CountrySearch";
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.countries.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.name, Value = s.code })))`

Comment: The code for your "Partial View" looks a lot like that for the Partial View Controller

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is with the call to `Html.RenderAction` in your main view.  Looking at the [MSDN documentation for RenderAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc.html.htmlhelperextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx), it expects us to pass in the `ActionMethod` name and the `Controller` name:

```
public static void RenderAction(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName = null,
    object routeValues = null
)
```

As written, your `RenderAction` call is passing "Search" for the `controllerName` parameter, however your controller name is CountrySearch, which causes routing to fail with this exception.

There are a couple of ways to work around this, but the simplest would be to update your `RenderAction` call to reflect the correct `Controller` name, like so:

`@{Html.RenderAction("CountrySearch", "CountrySearch");}`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [HttpGet]. According to this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211919/asp-net-mvc-execution-of-the-child-request-failed-please-examine-the-innerexc) . [HttpGet] only allows get requests but if there is a post request, it cannot find the method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback, I tried this but unfortunately the same error persists